# Python: TypeError - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

I'm writing a basic Python script, the code of which is as followsdef is_prime(n):

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while i<n:
        if(n%i == 0):
            return False
        i+=1
    return True

def truncable(num):
    li = []
    x = str(num)
    if(is_prime(num)):
        n = len(x)
        check = ""
        i = 1
        while(i<n):
            if(is_prime(x[i:])):
                check = "True"
            else:
                check = "False"
                break
        if(check == "True"):
            li.append(num)

print truncable(3797)
```

However, after running this script, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Note that if you'd been using Python 3, you would have gotten a much more helpful error message: `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()` which would have pointed out the underlying problem immediately.

Comment: Note that the `print` will result in `None`, since you aren't returning anything from `truncable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when `n` in the expression `n%i` is a string, not an integer. You made `x` a string, then passed it to `is_prime()`:

```
>>> is_prime('5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in is_prime
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>> is_prime(5)
True
```

Pass integers to `is_prime()` instead:

```
is_prime(int(x[i:]))
```

The `%` operator on a string is used for [string formatting operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

You appear to have forgotten to return anything from `truncable()`; perhaps you wanted to add:

```
return li
```

at the end?